# Mainframe to Cloud - File Based Processing

Tags: java, cloud, batch-processing, mainframe, private-cloud

We are working on migrating a high volume mainframe batch application to distributed/cloud using Java/Java Batch. 
The current application deals with a lot files (VSAM and FLAT - altogether 100+ files from different sources) and IO modules.
We are thinking of loading this data to Oracle database and then retrieve and process.
So there will be millions of transactions hitting Oracle DB.

We are concerned about performance on Oracle because of millions of transactions hitting the DB during the batch window.

Other approach we are considering is consuming files itself.

With NAS storage, the argument is even when reading/writing a file, its over the network.

Will we have any downside of file based processing in Cloud environment.

How can we scale the application depending on the size/load?

In the mordern world, how these kind of applications are migrated/rearchitected in cloud based/cloud friendly.

Using Hadoop/Spark clusters is not an option due to what ever reason.

Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: Did you consider Redis?

Comment: Redis is not durable enough for the kind of application that run on a mainframe, which are typically financial applications.

Comment: Redis can be configured for durability, although admittedly at the cost of some performance. Also, Hostbridge offers a [Redis for z/OS](https://www.hostbridge.com/redis-on-the-ibm-mainframe/) that provides inline code page conversion and an access layer right next to the host data, which could potentially be replicated to other Redis nodes. They offer their 32-bit version for free, so it may still be worth consideration by OP.

Comment: The data volume is very high. And we are planning to get that data to distributed/cloud servers and then process. So wondering any industry standards or anyone part of these kind of migrations and share experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert some of the workload over to zLinux? Load it onto DB/2 on z/OS, but use zLinux hosts for consumption? zLinux can run under z/VM so you could have many instances. This helps maximize your hardware investments.

Comment: How do we use in cloud? The main objective is to move to cloud and hence distributed.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "cloud" is just someone else's computer. The operation costs of a cloud model will far exceed those of a well tuned z/OS environment.

Comment: On cloud, we are not having any local storage - its a network storage and any write to the file assuming its writing to a local disk, is not true - there will be a lot of latency.